# SendGrid Emails Detecting Mobile vs. Tablet vs. Desktop Chart

Tags: charts, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3, amazon-quicksight

how can i detect  sendgrid email clients Mobile vs. Tablet vs. Desktop for example :

1. http://marketingland.com/34-percent-email-opens-now-happen-pc-83277
2. https://www.signupto.com/news/email-marketing-posts/analysing-your-performance-on-mobile-devices/

user agent string im getting from sendgrid

1. Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:11.0) Gecko Firefox/11.0 (via ggpht.com GoogleImageProxy)
2. Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Microsoft Outlook 14.0.7172; ms-office; MSOffice 14)
3. Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; XT1030 Build/SU6-7.7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/33.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36

problem here is when i receives email on gmail account. if i open my email on  cell phone browser signature "GoogleImageProxy"  same email if i open on desktop any browser signature is same "GoogleImageProxy", could be more same kind of issues gmail i noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [parsing the UA string](https://github.com/ua-parser)?

When I run those through an [online parser](https://www.whatismybrowser.com/developers/tools/user-agent-parser/) I see distinct data.

In general though, SendGrid, yourself, and everyone will be limited by what comes back in the UA string. 
But then again, how many people do you know who read their email from their cell browser, vs their phone's app? I think that's a very small edge case, and wouldn't worry about it.